# Mat-Sort won't sort when table is inside authenticated template

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, angular-material

I have a table, data comes from a firebase database.  Problem I'm having is sorting the table when using authentication.  I built the site on two stackblitz projects, one with and one without authentication.  The login info for the authenticated site: username is "test@test.com" and password is "asdfjkl;"

When you login to the authenticated site, you will see the sorting does not work, until that is you click the sortenable button, which re-runs the code

```
this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;
```

then the sorting works great.

Site without authentication (sorting works straight away):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sort-help-noauth

Site needing you to login (sorting won't work until the sort enable button is clicked):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sort-help

What am I doing wrong?  I don't want users to have to click a button to enable sorting.  Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suspect is the following:

Because of the `<ng-template>`, `@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;` doesn't get element.
(It isn't in the DOM. This happens with pagination for example).

What you can do:

**EASIER but not clean** : just hide the table (display:none) instead of the `<ng-template>`

**GOOD, but more complex**:

You define a route for you login which will redirect to an another route with the successfull connection. And in the component of this route, you will have your table.

Comment: Ok, changing it to have the table in its own component and using a route guard (which I'm now learning to do).  Once the user is logged in it will go to that component.  Thank you

Comment: Wandrille, wanted to let you know I did the route option you suggested.  Sorting works great.  Definitely an issue with my ng-template.  Thank you!